# How to pre-configure GeoServer in docker image?

Tags: geoserver, configuration, docker

I am using GeoServer 2.16.0 docker image build by myself based on [kartoza's dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/kartoza/geoserver/dockerfile).

The only pre-configuration is done via environment files, e.g. `geoserver.env`:

```
ENABLE_JSONP=true                                                                                                                                         
FOOTPRINTS_DATA_DIR=/opt/footprints_dir
GEOSERVER_ADMIN_PASSWORD=myawesomegeoserver
GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR=/opt/geoserver/data_dir
GEOSERVER_NODE_OPTS="id:$hostname - ($host_ip);background:red;color:white"
GEOWEBCACHE_CACHE_DIR=/opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc
#JAVA_OPTS="-Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en"
MAX_FILTER_RULES=20
OPTIMIZE_LINE_WIDTH=false
```

I would like to configure more, e.g. workspaces, stores, but cannot find any according documentation.

Is there any better way than the following?

1. Configuring a running container having the `DATA_DIR` mounted
2. Create an own image based in kartoza's and add the `DATA_DIR` content?

**Solution (16.02.2021)**

I added the following two lines to my dockerfile:

```
COPY ./data_dir_init /tmp/data_dir_init
COPY ./init-workspace.sh /scripts
```

The init-workspace.sh contains the following:

```
SETUP_LOCKFILE="${GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR}/.init_data_dir.lock"
if [ -f "${SETUP_LOCKFILE}" ]; then
    echo -e "\n\n Skip GeoServer init - already done\n\n"
    exit 0
fi

if [ "${DEBUG}" ]; then
    set -e
    set -x
fi

echo -e "\n\nStarting init of GeoServer data dir\n\n"

cp --verbose --recursive /tmp/data_dir_init/{styles,workspaces} $GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR
cp --verbose /tmp/data_dir_init/{csw,global,logging,wms,wps}.xml $GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR
mkdir--verbose --parents $GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR/data

if [ ! ${DEBUG} ]; then
    rm --recursive --verbose /tmp/data_dir_init
fi

# Put lock file to make sure data directory is not reinitialized on restart
touch ${SETUP_LOCKFILE}
```

The folder `data_dir_init` contains all content from the first session, when I startet an empty geoserver instance and created the base set-up I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either of those would work, or you could use the REST API to add the workspaces and stores when building your own image.

Comment: That's correct. In the end, I used the "empty" image with a mounted `DATA_DIR` volume and created my initial set-up. This set-up is "installed" during image creation.

Comment: @Eike could you please be more specific about how to use DATA_DIR to inyect the initial set-up on image build?

Comment: @luishromero: I added some more details to the question about my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a docker volume:

1. Create the volume:

```
geoserver:
  image: kartoza/geoserver:2.19.0
  volumes:
    - ${PWD}/tmp/geoserver_data_dir:/opt/geoserver/data_dir
```

2. Configure geoserver one time
3. Commit the volume

Next person will have geoserver automatically setup based on the volume you commited!